# Why wpf ListViewItem backgound do not work?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to change the default item highlighting. Only the BorderThickness property works in the IsMouseOver trigger. Background and BorderBrush don't work.
On the image "Item 2" IsMouseOver
[Image](https://ibb.co/WKqNmY1)

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2F0BFC" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1"></TextBlock>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: There is probably a conflicting style change when an item is hovered / selected

Comment: IsSelected trigger doesn't work. BorderThickness property only.